# Continuity Conveyed by Open Covers

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Here's a statement.

Given a map between topological spaces $f:X\rightarrow Y.$ For any open subset $V$ of $Y,$ $f_V$ denotes the restriction map $f|_{f^{-1}(V)}:f^{-1}(V)\rightarrow V,$  both equipped with the subspace topology. Then for any open cover $V_j(j\in J)$ of $Y,$ if $f_{V_j}$ is a continuous map on $f^{-1}(V_j),$ for every $j\in J,$ then $f$ is a continuous map on $X.$

I doubt if this statement is false, because for any $j\in J,$ we cannot get whether $f^{-1}(V_j)$ is open or not, and don't know how to imply the conclusion. However, I still cannot provide a counterexample to disprove it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What can you conclude by considering the open cover $\{Y\}$ of $Y$?

Comment: @MPW Then that is a correct example right, but will it imply anything?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your hypothesis is that each $f_{V_j}$ is continuous whenever $\{V_j\}_j$ is an open cover of $Y$, and you are trying to conclude that $f$ is continuous. Can you show that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f_Y$ is continuous? If so, then  you have shown what you want, and the only open cover that really matters is the one I mentioned. *Hint:* For any $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U) = f_Y^{-1}(U\cap f(X))$.

Comment: @MPW But I wrote for any open cover, if the restriction map is continuous, then $f$ is continuous. So I think this statement requires to check for any open covers. I think what you said is the following statement: if for any open cover, the restriction map is continuous, then $f$ is, too.  Would I misunderstand it and have some logical mistakes?

Comment: Okay, did I misread it? Is the hypothesis "Let $\mathscr V$ be a fixed open cover of $Y$, and suppose that $f_V$ is continuous for each $V\in\mathscr V$", or is it "Suppose that $f_V$ is continuous for every open cover $\mathscr V$ of $Y$ and every $V\in \mathscr V$" ?

Comment: @MPW I think it is the former. Do I make any logical mistake in my question?

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) is useful (the pasting lemma)?

Comment: I believe I was using the latter interpretation, not the former. So I may be wrong.

Comment: In the link the counter example seems not using the topology induced by the original space, but is really a practical idea~ thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve this problem by the following simple example:

For $f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow\{1,2\},$ $1\mapsto 1, 2\mapsto 2,$ let the domain be equipped with the trivial topology and the range with the discrete topology. Then $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ is an open cover and the restriction are both continuous, even homeomorphism, while $f$ is not continuous, let alone homeomorphism.

Thanks for @MPW your help!